# destroy a record once all of its belongs_to associations are destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to destroy `Book` once its owners(i.e. the records it belongs to) are destroyed.

If there are only one `belongs_to` relationship, the `dependent` option simple works.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

But if there are more `belongs_to` relationship? For instance:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

I want to destroyed the `Book` once **all** of its owners are destroyed. If a `Cart` and a `Shop` own the same `Book`, and the `Shop` is destroyed but `Cart` isn't, the `Book` wouldn't be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want a polymorphic belongs_to association.

I am still checking on the `:dependent => :destroy` for it...

Research found " This option should not be specified when belongs_to is used in conjunction with a has_many relationship on another class because of the potential to leave orphaned records behind." which is not quite the same but seems to hint that it will be a manual process, i.e. remove both `dependent => :destroy` statements and remove child/parent records programmaticaly (manually).